# Google cloud hosting - Connection timed out after

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I was trying to delete a previous WordPress deployment on Google Cloud platform that I didn't want and suddenly I saw these errors. I can connect with FileZilla after increasing time out up to 120 seconds, I can also connect with `ssh.cloud.google.com`, but the site keep on timing out. I have delete cache on CloudFlare.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't provide details I'll assume you are using SFTP to connect to a Linux instance as explained on [Google Cloud docs.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#filebrowser)

Open a shell to the instance that hosts your FTP server and edit the following file (make a backup of the file before editing anything, just in case)

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

And find this value:

```
# Google Compute Engine times out connections after 10 minutes of inactivity.
# Keep alive ssh connections by sending a packet every 2 minutes.
ClientAliveInterval 120
```

Change the 120 to any other value you want (Remember you need root access to edit it and be careful, you could lock yourself out of the instance if you change what you shouldn't).

Then reload the ssh service:

```
sudo systemctl reload ssh.service
```

Comment: The machine wasn't able to handle the request that it was getting and there were some plugins that were making too frequent requests. I removed some of the plugins, added disk RAM and slightly increased my server capacity

Comment: Hi! would you mind writing as an answer what was happening and how you solved it? So future users have a reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did 5 things:

1. I deactivated Jetpack and deleted
2. Cleared all offline files (Caching plugin and WordPress popular post plugin) i.e. cache files
3. Customized my computer engine installation by just increasing the RAM by about 2G
4. Restarted Apache
5. Lastly, I Installed and activated Jetpack but enabled only a few modules I needed